# MVC - Update model in view after ajax form submit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question concerning MVC4. I have a form that I submit through ajax to my controller. In the controller, I create a new entry in a database, using the data of the form.

- In case of success, the form fields need to go empty and a message should appear that the record has been added. So that the user is ready to add the next item through the form. I can clear the fields in the "ResetView" method through javascript (that's called through "OnSuccess"), that's not a problem
- In case of error, the form fields need to remain filled in and a message should appear that it failed. In my case, it calls also the "OnFailure" method "ShowError" (which just shows the div "CustomerMessage").

The issue I am having when an item fails, is that the "CustomMessage" from my model is empty, while I did explicitly set it in my controller. So in my view, the @Model.CustomMessage is always empty!

I read that I should call the "ModelState.Clear()" function in my controller but that doesn't seem to do anything.
Can someone check what could be wrong in my code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

View:

```
<div id="createform">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Payment", new { username = User.Identity.Name }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "createform",
    //OnBegin = "SubmitForm",
    OnSuccess = "ResetView",
    OnFailure = "ShowError"
}))
{      
   <div id="CustomMessage">@Model.CustomMessage</div>
   ... bunch of @Html.TextBoxFor stuff (like below) ...
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SenderName, new { id = "SenderName"})
}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PaymentViewModel payment, string username)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                paymentRepository.AddPayment(payment.PaymentLine, username);
                paymentRepository.SaveChanges();

                payment.CustomMessage = "success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                payment.CustomMessage = "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            payment.CustomMessage = "error";
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView(payment);
}
```

Comment: `ModelState.Clear()` has nothing to do with it. You will never hit your `OnFailure()` function because nothing fails on the server - all you ever do is return a partial view (not return a HttpException)

Comment: Hi, ok but if I always display the div "CustomMessage" (regardless of success or failure), even then the @Model.CustomMessage is empty. While I would expect it to have either the value "success" or "error" after I submit the form.. Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: You have not shown the code `ResetView()` and `ShowError()` - how are you 'displaying' the error?

Comment: And why are you replacing the form all over again? Hardly any point using ajax for this since your not gaining any performance benefit. You should be just returning the message (ContentResult) and using `UpdateTargetId = "CustomMessage"`

Comment: Hi, If I only return the ContentResult, I'll loose my form entries. So if something goes wrong, all the fields are empty again and the user needs to type everything again. I want to avoid this. And for the code of ResetView() or ShowError(), I left these empty for now. I just want to know why the value of @Model.CustomMessage is empty after I return my view in the controller

Comment: I'm assuming your not really understanding what/when to use ajax. There is no point in this case (in fact you may well be degrading performance, not to mention other issues such as needing to re-parse the validator etc.). Either just do a normal submit and have MVC handle everything out of the box. If you do want to improve performance, then get rid of the obsolete `Ajax.BeginForm()` and use `$.ajax()` to serialize and submit the form and return a message to update your DOM (do not regenerate the form all over again)

Comment: And BTW - `new { id = "SenderName"}` is just setting the `id` attribute to what it already is (again, it pointless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It seemed that I was missing a reference to the jquery unobtrusive ajax script. After adding that, everything worked correctly

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```